# Рациональные операции при сравнении файлов

Tags: файлы

**Задача** — получить 2 одинаковых файла в 2 местах (папках к примеру)

Решение 1 «в лоб» — удалить первый, скопировать на его место второй.

Решение 2 — «быстро» сравнить файлы и заменить, если они разные.

**Вопрос 1** — какими методами можно «быстро» сравнить файлы?

На данный момент сравниваю размер. Однако один размер, не достаточное доказательство, что файлы равны. Как и разный размер, не достаточное доказательство, что файлы разные. (при необычных случаях можно наткнутся на неправильную оценку)

Появляется необходимость сравнить файлы как то дополнительно. 
Предлагали сравнить по хешу. Но, как я понимаю, для такого сравнения нужно прочесть оба файла полностью, затем преобразовать информацию в хеш и уже после сравнить их. Такие манипуляции вряд ли заметно быстрее, чем удаление и копирование файла.

Предлагали просто сравнивать файлы по байтово. Тоже не самый рациональный способ, как мне кажется.

Как реализовать базу хешей заранее, которая будет обновляться на постоянной основе не знаю, поскольку файлы могут изменится в любом из 2 мест, а держать активной софтину может не быть возможности.

**Вопрос 2** - Какими методами пользуются программы для синхронизации?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67649/discussion-on-question-by-opossum-----).